# Autocomplete command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

Here's my autocomplete tag. Is this correct? Because it isn't working properly for me.

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag('srches_name','' ,autocomplete_srches_name_products_path, :size => 75) %>
```

Comment: what do you means properly?

Comment: I've created a search tab, which searches for products. I've used form_tag for the search tab. In that form_tag i've used the above autocomplete_field_tag in place of text_field_tag.

Comment: It's not auto-completing.

Comment: Check your consoles for errors, both your server and a java console if you have one.